# How to properly initialise controls in an instantiated view controller?

Tags: objective-c

I have a class `ErrorMessageViewController`:

```
// ErrorMessageViewController.h
@interface ErrorMessageViewController: UIViewController {
    NSString * tempTitle;
    NSString * tempContent;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* messageTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* messageContent;
-(void) initTitle:(NSString *)title andContent:(NSString *)content;
@end

// ErrorMessageViewController.m
@implementation ErrorMessage
@synthesize messageTitle, messageContent;

-(void) initTitle:(NSString *)title andContent:(NSString *)content {
    tempTitle = title == nil ? @"" : title;
    tempContent = content == nil ? @"" : content;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (messageTitle != nil) { [messageTitle setText:tempTitle]; }
    if (messageContent != nil) { [messageContent setText:tempContent]; }
}

@end
```

And then I put it into display using this code:

```
NSString * errorMessage = @"Duplicate ID";
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ErrorMessageViewController * errorMessage = (ErrorMessageViewController *)
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ErrorMessage"];
[errorMessage initTitle:@"Error" andContent:contentVar];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:errorMessage animated:YES];
```

When I debug it, on `initTitle:Content:`, the `tempTitle` and `tempContent` is `NSCFConstString` "Error" and `NSCFString` "Duplicate ID".

But then the flow goes to `viewWillAppear`, and both the `tempTitle` and `tempContent` 's contents are gone, replaced with `NSCFString` and `NSObject`. The tempTitle assignment is still OK because it's still string, though I don't know what the content is, but the tempContent assignment produce error. I can't even NSLog the `tempContent` value.

Why is this happened? Why the contents of the object change, like it was never initialised?

Comment: Why not make sure messageTitle and messageContent are initialized in initWithTitle:andContent:? It would remove the need for tempTitle and tempContent and would make the code much cleaner IMHO.

Comment: @JorisH I can't. If I set the `messageTitle` and `messageContent` before `pushViewController:animated:`, the `messageTitle` and `messageContent` will still empty. It looks like the objects still haven't created or initialized yet at that time. So I need to put it to local variable first, and then do the init on either `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, or `viewDidAppear`, when the object has already fully initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your data like this.

```
NSString * errorMessage = @"Duplicate ID";
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ErrorMessageViewController * errorMessage = (ErrorMessageViewController *)
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ErrorMessage"];
errorMessage.messageTitle = @"Error";
errorMessage.messageContent = errorMessage;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:errorMessage animated:YES];
```

and use those variable directly in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // Use your variables 
}
```

**Edit :**

```
-(void) initTitle:(NSString *)title andContent:(NSString *)content {
    tempTitle = (title == nil ? @"" : title);
    tempContent = (content == nil ? @"" : content);
}

NSString * errorMessage = @"Duplicate ID";
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ErrorMessageViewController *vc = (ErrorMessageViewController *)
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ErrorMessage"];
[vc initTitle:@"Error" andContent:errorMessage];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Hope this will help

Comment: This works! Why I can't use method to set my properties?

Comment: You can use methods to set your properties but what you are doing wrong is you are calling string with that method check my updated answer for method calling.

Answer (score 1):

Storyboard is use lazy loading to load the subviews.  `messageTitle` is not initialized after called `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. Call `self.messageTitle` to make the view initialized before set value.

```
ErrorMessageViewController * errorMessage = (ErrorMessageViewController *)
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ErrorMessage"];

//tempTitle = nil
// [errorMessage initTitle:@"Error" andContent:contentVar]; 

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:errorMessage animated:YES];
// set value after push
[errorMessage initTitle:@"Error" andContent:contentVar];
```

Comment: What do you mean with "call self.messageTitle" ? Do you mean I need to call `errorMessage.messageTitle;` first before `[[errorMessage messageTitle] setTitle:]` ?

Comment: I think messageTitle is nil when you call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier because of storyboard lazyLoad.